# Dynamically allocating character array in class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make my own string class, and I'm trying to create the constructor. So far I'm having a little struggle.

I have my function prototypes defined in a header file and the variable buffer defined in the header file like this `char *buffer;`, in a new cpp file I'm trying to define the constructor like this:

```
mystring::mystring(const char *s)
{
    int counter = strlen(s)+1;
    *buffer = generate_c_array(counter);
}

char * mystring::generate_c_array(int size)
{
  return new char[size];
}
```

I'm basically trying to make it such that `buffer` is a char array of size `s+1` and contains the contents of `s` followed by a null terminator. Though, this is causing my program to crash.

I'm not sure how to assign buffer correctly, does this look correct?

Comment: What is the purpose of `counter` and its for loop?

Comment: @NickyC I'm counting the number of elements in the char array passed to the constructor so I can generate a dynamically allocated array of the right size.

Comment: @NickyC it is an obfuscated way to write `counter = strlen(s)+1;`

Comment: @unicornication why not just use `strlen`?

Comment: @tobi303 that is probably a better idea haha I didn't realize! I was using the second constructor's for loop

Comment: @NickyC thank you! neglected to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write your code

```
mystring::mystring(const char *s)
{
    sz = strlen(s) // sz- another data member, holds size
    buffer = new char[sz + 1];
    strcpy(buffer, s); // assuming s is null-terminated
}
```

The for loop and counter were not necessary, in fact

Comment: I tried to do `buffer = new char[strlen(s) +1];
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer);i++)
    {
        cout << buffer[i];
    }` and this prints garbage data, is the pointer reference required?

Comment: If you want data, That need to be copied, It was not there in the code, updating now

Answer (score 1):

You assign to the specific character in the `buffer`,  not to the variable `buffer`. Change to:

```
buffer = generate_c_array(counter);
```

Other than that, `strdup` will do the same job for you, but you will have to deallocate with `free()`. In current code you actually don't really copy, you will have to do `strcpy(buffer, s)` unless using the `strdup` mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping over length of the string `s`?

If you need length of the string use it directly:

```
std::size_t length = strlen(s);
buffer = generate_c_array(length + 1);

// Copy your string:    
memcpy(buffer, s, length)

// Add the terminator character:  
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't copied the content..
2. If you want to assign a pointer ( which is what `new` give you ) to another pointer, you don't need `*`.
3. `strncpy` do the copying for you.

---

```
mystring::mystring(const char *s)
{
    int counter = strlen(s)+1;
    char* buffer = generate_c_array(counter);
    strncpy(buffer, s, counter);
}

char * mystring::generate_c_array(int size)
{
  return new char[size];
}
```